# Breadcrumb not showing in Umbraco Site

Tags: macros, umbraco

I created a partial view macro file in my umbraco backoffice for a breadcrumb. I inserted the macro to my masterPage and ran the site, but I couldn't see anthing. No breadcrumb navigation, no errors, jsut nothing. What could be wrong?

Please see the breadcrumb code below

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@*
    This snippet makes a breadcrumb of parents using an unordered html list.

    How it works:
    - It uses the Ancestors() method to get all parents and then generates links so the visitor can go back
    - Finally it outputs the name of the current page (without a link)
*@

@{ var selection = CurrentPage.Ancestors(); }

@if (selection.Any())
{
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        @* For each page in the ancestors collection which have been ordered by Level (so we start with the highest top node first) *@
        @foreach (var item in selection.OrderBy("Level"))
        {
            <li><a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
        }

        @* Display the current page as the last item in the list *@
        <li class="active">@CurrentPage.Name</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Please Help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Did you create a childpage that uses the masterpage? Also if you set a breakpoint on `var selection = ...` and debug it do you see anything for selection or is this null?

Comment: Also note this will only show on child pages no the main page i.e. wont show anything on the home page but will do on pages under the home page because the homepage is doesn't have any "ancestor" pages.

Comment: @denfordmutseriwa Thanks for your response too. I need it to show on all pages that inherit the master page. Can you please point me to the right direction on how to do that?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Can you provide us with an example of your content tree structure, and how you are trying to render the macro in code?

Answer (score 0):

so below is my standard breadcrumb code i use, this is in a partial view that sits on the master page

```
    @inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var selection = Model.Content.Ancestors().ToList();
    if (selection.Any())
        {
        var currentPageTitle = Model.Content.Name;
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            @foreach (var item in selection.OrderBy("Level"))
                {
                var pageTitle = item.Name;
                <li>
                    <a href="@item.Url" title="@pageTitle">
                        @pageTitle
                    </a>
                </li>
                }
            <li class="active">
                @currentPageTitle
            </li>
        </ul>
        }
}
```

As i mentioned to you before this will only show on pages under the home page see example image of my content tree below.

[image: umbraco content tree]

All pages from about going down and under any of them will show the bread crumb and home page wont (because it doesn't have any ancestors i.e. its the first page in the tree).

I got a feeling you content tree is not nested like the one above i.e. all pages are on the same level as the home page, can you please add a picture of what your content tree looks like.